# Can't connect to local MySQL DB using the .NET connector

Tags: .net, mysql, visual-studio-2010

I've got a locally installed MySQL database server that I want to use for development for my MVC 2 project.  I installed the 64 bit version of MySQL and set up my schemas.  I didn't change any of the defaults except for the root password.  I've also installed the 32 bit .NET connector and I'm using VS2010.

I can't get VS to connect to MySQL.  I set the server to "localhost" (also have tried 127.0.0.1), user name to "root", and the password.  It can't connect.  I've also tried specifying the database I want to connect to with no luck.  I can, however, ping the server via "mysqladmin -h localhost -u root -p XXX ping".

Something interesting that I noticed was that when I opened the Advanced options, the connection string that the connector was building under the options didn't include a password, just "server=localhost;username=root" and whatever options I fiddled with.  I'm guessing that's for security reasons, but if it's not adding the password to the connection string that's obviously a problem (that I don't know how to fix).

I have to admit that databases and networking aren't my strong suits, but I still didn't anticipate this much trouble.  I'm beginning to think that I might have set up my database incorrectly, but I'm not sure what to look for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out a good while back, should have updated this a long time ago.  My MySQL server didn't install correctly for some reason, and reinstalling was a pain because the process kept failing when I tried to reinstall it.  I did manage to find a solution to the problem here: https://serverfault.com/questions/214435/error-1067-the-process-terminated-unexpectedly-when-trying-to-install-mysql-o

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error. I changed `localhost` for `127.0.0.1` instead and it seems to work for me.

I'm still looking for the reason why Windows doesn't let me use `localhost` (because, as I've read already, it's a Windows error).

Answer (score 0):

Localhost is `::1` in IPv6.

It tries to connect with IPv4, which is `127.0.0.1`.